# Groovy Config.groovy file - Hotswapping

Tags: groovy

Is config.groovy compiled or can a parameter be changed at runtime and the application restarted? I have a use case where I may need to change a config parameter in production and then restart the app so the bootstrapper picks it up but if the .groovy files are compiled then that wouldn't be possible, of course.

I do not have a test scenario for this.